# ASP.NET Plugin architecture with no MVC where plugins serve aspx pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, plugins

I need to create an ASP.NET application that supports plugins. I've written plugin applications before by:

- Designating a folder in the main app where all plugin DLLs are located
- Main app contains a base class, PluginBase, which has all methods required to interact with the plugin
- Each plugin contains a class that inherits from PluginBase
- Upon startup, main app iterates through DLL files, then over their types, finds any type that extends PluginBase, creates it and interacts with plugins that way. Alternatively, it's possible to use MEF, which seems to be a lot easier.

Now I need to extend the same concept to an ASP.NET application that has plugins that contain .aspx pages. The paradigm above doesn't really work: plugin projects are ASP.NET applications and, thus, don't compile into a single DLL. Although it's technically possible, I really don't think this is the right approach. While the class that extends PluginBase can be loaded using the pattern described above, aspx pages don't seem to work - I get numerous runtime compilation errors.

I've tried the following:

- Instead of just copying a plugin dll, I copy the project folder to the plugin folder. I also copy the project dll to that same folder, so I can load it and get the actual plugin type
- My PluginBase contains an abstract property MainPagePath, which is where a plugin would specify a path to its entry page. The idea is that every other page served by that plugin would be linked from that page.

However, this approach is giving me runtime compilation errors. I was wondering if there's a well-established paradigm for architecting this kind of an application?